# How to Page Break Group Header if Details is on Another Page

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

Please see the above image

The group header title is on the bottom and the details are on the next page. What I want to achieve is that, if no single detail after the title, the group header title will be on the next page. Thank You

Comment: Check "New Page after" option for the section above the Group header. Also, will this be a case for every scenario, that you need this header on a new page? Even if data of section above does not extend this long?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/404043/How-to-set-a-page-section-break-for-a-new-page-in

Comment: @JulyOrdinary There are times that when there are still spaces after 3rd Trimester 2016-2017 (Group Header)  e.g 10 lines, 1 line is below the Group Header , the other 9 will be on the next pages (which is ok), but on the picture above, all the details are on the next pages, leaving the group header alone in the bottom (not ok)